# Windows8 PC cannot recognise my password and requires to change it on Account.live

Tags: windows-8, passwords

I switched off my new PC. During the previous session I may have entered a new password when trying to get Skype on it via Windows shop.  I tried to enter the password several times but now the PC is asking me to change the password in live.account.  It does not seem to work and I can no longer use that PC.

My PC which may not be able to connect via WIFI because one of my WIFI connection does not connect to the internet. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Change the password on your live account and connect your Windows PC to the router via an Ethernet cable. Reboot PC. This should enable internet connectivity on your Windows PC after the reboot, and when you enter the password, it will check it online, which would have changed by now and allow you to log in.